# Parse.com Query with swift 1.2 and string array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I am trying to query from parse.com and I would db receiving about 100 objects per time. I used the swift example code on their website, and the app doesn't build with that code. So I looked around and found that people were using code similar to this:

```
 var query = PFQuery(className:"posts")
    query.whereKey("post", equalTo: "true")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // do something


        self.myDataArray = objects as! [String]

    })
```

This does not work, because I am trying to convert PFObject to String

I would need to get the one one value from each object into a swift string array [String]. How do I get just the one text value, instead of the PFObject and how do I get it into the swift string array?

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak swift very well, but the problem with the code is it's trying to cast the returned `PFObject` to a string, but you want to extract a string attribute, so (if you really want to do it):

```
for object in objects {
    var someString = object.valueForKey("someAttributeName") as String
    self.myDataArray.addObject(someString)
}
```

But please make sure you need to do this.  I've noticed a lot of new parse/swift users (especially those who are populating tables) have the urge to discard the returned `PFObject`s in favor of just one of their attributes.  Consider keeping the `PFObject`s and extracting the attributes later as you need them.  You might find you'll need other attributes, too.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would definitely recommend using the "if let" pattern to qualify your incoming data. This is a nice Swift feature that will help avoid run-time errors.

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"posts")
query.whereKey("post", equalTo: "true")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(
{ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    // check your incoming data and try to cast to array of "posts" objects.
    if let foundPosts = objects as? [posts]
    {   
        // iterate over posts and try to extract the attribute you're after
        for post in foundPosts
        {   
            // this won't crash if the value is nil
            if let foundString = post.objectForKey("keyForStringYouWant") as? String
            {
                // found a good data value and was able to cast to string, add it to your array!
                self.myDataArray.addObject(foundString)
            }
        }
})
```

Comment: This leaves this error. I tried changing it to a [PFObject] but then I got more errors below. "Use of undeclared type 'posts'